# path to strings in HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I generate all the paths to text strings in a HTML document, preferably using BeautifulSoup? 
I have f.e. this code:

```
<DIV class="art-info"><SPAN class="time"><SPAN class="time-date" content="2012-02-28T14:46CET" itemprop="datePublished">
             28. february 2012
            </SPAN>
            14:46
           </SPAN></DIV><DIV>
           Something,<P>something else</P>continuing.
          </DIV>
```

I'd like to divide HTML code into paths to text strings, like

```
str1 >>>  <DIV class="art-info"><SPAN class="time"><SPAN class="time-date" content="2012-02-28T14:46CET" itemprop="datePublished">28. february 2012</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
str2 >>>  <DIV class="art-info"><SPAN class="time">14:46</SPAN></DIV>
str3 >>>  <DIV>Something,continuing.</DIV>
str4 >>>  <DIV><P>something else</P></DIV>
```

or

```
str1 >>>  <DIV><SPAN><SPAN>28. february 2012</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
str2 >>>  <DIV><SPAN>14:46</SPAN></DIV>
str3 >>>  <DIV>Something,continuing.</DIV>
str4 >>>  <DIV><P>something else</P></DIV>
```

or

```
str1 >>>  //div/span/span/28. february
str2 >>>  //div/span/14:46
str3 >>>  //div/Something,continuing.
str4 >>>  //div/p/something else
```

I've studied BeautifulSoup documentation, but I can't figure out how to do it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you're trying to do. Could you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: I'd like to generate all the paths to text strings in HTML document. In a simplified way, I'd like to get something like //html/body/div/div/span/"string" for the first found nontag text, then f.e. html/body/div/div/span/h3/p/"text string" for the second nontag text, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
file=open("input")
soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
for t in soup(text=re.compile(".")):
  path = '/'.join(reversed([p.name for p in t.parentGenerator() if p]))
  print path+"/"+ t.strip()
```

**Output**

```
[document]/html/body/div/span/span/28. february 2012
[document]/html/body/div/span/14:46
[document]/html/body/div/Something,
[document]/html/body/div/p/something else
[document]/html/body/div/continuing.
```